# Jackson - Deserialize array as String

Tags: android, mapping, jackson, deserialization

Is there a way to deserialize this:

```
public List<CustomeObject> list;
```

to a String like this:

```
"[{first_custome_object}, {second_custome_object}]"
```

When I'm trying to do so I get "There was a problem when sending the request.
    org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_ARRAY token"

Can I "force" this list to be deserialized to a string?

Comment: Have a look at gson an the deserialize example in here http://www.javacreed.com/gson-deserialiser-example/

Comment: I do not understand your question. Deserialization means - convert JSON to Java objects. Serialization means - convert Java objects to JSON. What are you trying to do? Do you want to serialize `List<CustomeObject> list` to JSON or deserialize JSON to `List<CustomeObject> list`? Could you also show your code and `CustomeObject` properties?